# Does the name eth0 matter?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, debian, bridge

I'm running Debian as the host and have a bridge for the kvm virtual machines. The bridge setup looks something like this:

```
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.100
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
```

I'm interested in the line `bridge_ports eth0`. My understanding is that this line shadows the real eth0 and exposes some bridge features for the virtual machine to be able to use, however, physically it represents eth0. Would you please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Also in the interface config file. I don't see eth0 mentioned elsewhere. So I'm wondering whether eth0 is a keyword that the operating systems knows it represents the network interface? Or the name eth0 doesn't matter, and could be changed to anything else?

Answer (score 1):

you're right that `bridge_ports eth0` represent network interface. It means (more or less) 'packets which comes to vmbr0 from guests redirect to eth0 on host'.

Eth0 is first ethernet network interface on host. When you invoke ie. `ifconfig` you can see all of your interfaces. There will be lo (loopback, localhost), ethx (ethernet cards), there can be wlanx (wifi cards), tun/tap (vpn) and many many more. You should know what is interface you want to use.

More information about network configuration you can find on https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

Comment: Thanks @OndraSniperFlidr, so does the name `eth0` have to be `eth0`? Is it by convention or it has to be?

Comment: It has to be if you want to use primary ethernet to access LAN and WAN. But you should know if you need to use other interface, so you can take it as has to be. My recommendation for you is to study something about networking and interfaces in Linux.

Comment: Yes, this is my learning process. So where is the interface name defined? It seems it doesn't work if I change eth0 to abc0.

Comment: It's defined by OS itself, based on type of interface. ethx for ethernet, lo for loopback, wlanx for wifi etc.